# Customer connect to magento2 from cakephp

Tags: magento2.3

I need to create a script that let customer to get status connected on Magento 2 when he connect in an external website (CakePhp)
NB: Magento and CakePhp are in the same server.

when I use this script:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$storeManager = $obj->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$productMetadata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');

$customerEmail ="test@gmail.com";

$CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$CustomerModel->setWebsiteId(1); //Here 1 means Store ID**
$CustomerModel->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
$customerId = $CustomerModel->getId();

echo $customerId ;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
// Load customer
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
// Load customer session
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "Customer Logged in";
}else{
    echo "customer is Not Logged in";
}
?>
```

When I execute this code I have this error in cakephp

```
Error: Cannot redeclare Zend\Diactoros\createUploadedFile()
File /vendor/laminas/laminas-diactoros/src/functions/create_uploaded_file.legacy.php
```